# Are there any active moderators on Aviation?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I recently [posted a question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102295/why-are-there-still-fighter-pilots-in-cockpits) on SE.Aviation, and it got many views and lots of answers. Great! However I noticed what seemed to be a lack of the moderation I'm used to seeing on other SEs. Every comment (and there are many) and every answer, no matter how off-topic, remains up, without even suggestions from a moderator. This leaves me wondering:

As of the date of this question, are there any active moderators on Aviation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are [four of us](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) at the time of writing, however we try not to be too heavy handed with moderation as this site may be a little more relaxed than you might be used to elsewhere on the network.

If there are specific things you want to bring to our attention, please feel free to flag them.

Comment: Great! Relaxed is good, and it seems every site has its own flavor.

Answer (score 2):

The voting system is sufficient to separate good from poor answers. This is not Wikipedia.

Also, in my opinion, every answer to the specific question you linked to was on topic enough to stay on the page.